# high dimensional particular fibre

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Let $f \colon \mathbf{C}^{2n} \to \mathbf{C}^n$ be a dominant algebraic morphism. By the fiber dimension theorem, the generic fiber of $f$ is of dimension $n$ and dimensions of particular fibers can jump up. I am looking for an example of $f$ that has a particular fiber of dimension $\sim 2n$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do in this situation is a fiber of dimension $2n-1$, and here is an example showing that it's possible. Letting $x_i$ be coordinates on $\Bbb C^{2n}$, the map $$(x_1,\cdots,x_{2n})\mapsto (x_1,x_1x_{n+2},\cdots,x_1x_{2n})$$ suffices: if the first coordinate of a point in $\Bbb C^n$ is not zero, then it is in the image of this map, so the map is dominant; the fiber over the origin is $V(x_1)\subset\Bbb C^{2n}$, a linear space of dimension $2n-1$.